# Python 2 bug replaces my string value with u'intentional/'

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

I am using Python2 and furl library (https://github.com/gruns/furl/blob/master/API.md#fragment) to get query strings from an URL, using smth like:

```
url = furl(url) 
for (name, val) in url.asdict()['query']['params']:
        query_params[name] = val
```

One of my params is id=AAA and when I print my query_params dict it shows this:
**{'id': u'intentional/'}**

Where did this come from?

Comment: Because that is the `repr` of a `unicdod` object in Python 2. By the way, you should **really not be using Python 2**. It is no longer officially supported.

Comment: This decision is not up to me, but how can I at least print the whole dict as string?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: It's not clear from your code why a query param `id=AAA` should result in `{'id': u'intentional/'}`. You should be aware, though, that query params can have repeated keys, ie. `URL?id=AAA&id=intentional`. Typically, URL-related libraries provide distinct methods to either include only the last value or to aggregate all values in a list. Check the furl docs and carefully inspect input/output to narrow down the source of the mismatch.